# Select table names with specific pattern

Tags: sql

I created a query to get all table names with `"prefix_"`

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'prefix_%' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

But in my database, I have tables with prefix_prefix_. 
How to avoid selecting them?

Comment: `and not like...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by just adding the exception to the where clause.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'prefix_%' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'prefix_prefix_%' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: great answer, I'll answer it asap. Can I invite you to the chat. I have another question if you have time I would've be greatful  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql

Answer (score 2):

You can try using subquery and not like

```
   select * from 
   (
     SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'prefix_%' and AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
   )A where ABLE_NAME LIKE 'prefix_prefix_%'
```